# How to get the latest email using CFIMAP

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using the below code block in CF9 to get all the mail data,

```
<cfimap
    action="GETHEADERONLY"
    name="LOCAL.checkEmail"
    secure="true"
    folder="Inbox"
    server="#ImportAquireMailServer#"
    username="#ImportAquireUsername#"
    password="#ImportAquirePassword#" />
```

This query object provides the information about all the mails present in inbox. While doing so it takes a lot of time and also times out frequently.

Is there any way to get the latest mail only, so that it will not provide the information about all the mails and will also not run into time out situation?

Please help.

Comment: I had never heard of this tag so I googled it.  The documentation makes mention of StartRow and MaxRows attributes.   Sounds like it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Dan, How will I decide first what will be my start row and max rows as I have no idea how many mails are there in the inbox.

Comment: If it were my problem, I'd do some trial and error to see how the tag works in various situations.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing built in. You can get the total count via undocumented methods.  However, from what I have read, identifying the "latest" message is [a bit more involved than you might think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725063/how-to-download-only-new-emails-from-imap).  It was more straightforward with pop3.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to update the read messages to "read" like:

```
<cfimap action="MarkRead" connection = "Conn" messagenumber="#getHeaders.messagenumber#">
```

after the message id done with work.

so you can query the latest messages as:

```
 <cfquery dbtype="query" name="getMails">
  select * from getHeaders 
  where seen=<cfqueryparam value="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
</cfquery>also you can filter with received date
```

you can refer http://shemy-coldfusion.blogspot.in/2013/03/coldfusion-code-to-get-multiple-mail.html